# Why is my email not getting sent in my Pimcore Symfony workflow?

Tags: php, symfony, pimcore

I want to send mail to the user who got activated through workflow.
The issue is email is not getting sent. I have tried it by changing notifyingUsers to my email address but that also not worked. Below is my workflow file.

```
pimcore:
    workflows:
        user_workflow:
            label: "User Activation"
            type: "state_machine"
            supports:
                - \Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Users
            marking_store:
                type: "single_state"
                arguments:
                    - isActive
            places:
                inActive:
                    label: "In Active"
                    color: 'red'
                    permissions:
                        - condition: "is_fully_authenticated() and 'ROLE_PIMCORE_ADMIN' in role_names"
                          modify: true
                Active:
                    label: "Active"
                    permissions:
                        - condition: "is_fully_authenticated() and 'ROLE_PIMCORE_ADMIN' in role_names"
                          modify: true          
            transitions:
                Activate:
                    from: inActive
                    to: Active
                    options:
                        label: "Activate the User"
                        notificationSettings:
                           - notifyUsers: ['admin']
                             channelType: 
                                - mail
                             mailType: template 
                             mailPath: '/content/mailTemplate.html.twig' #this is the value
                    guard: "is_fully_authenticated() and (is_granted('ROLE_PIMCORE_ADMIN') )"
```